# Twitter Api giving only tweets of Last Couple of days

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recently I implemented OAuth in our Ruby on Rails application with OAuth gem and started using it.

Technology :- Ruby On Rails

Before Implementing OAuth, I use to call the below URL it use to give the tweets properly,

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=moxie&count=100

But, After Implementing Oauth, I am calling the Below URL :-

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=moxie&count=100

Which is not giving the Tweets properly, i.e the result set is containing only Tweets of last couple of Days.

How to retrieve tweets from last two months or more than that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

check your api request limit, o try to split your request, by 50 tweats

Comment: I had one twitter test account, In which it had only 34 tweets.but still its returning only 3 tweets which i tweeted last 2days